# Designing a spark job with a csv containing records with different schemas

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a huge csv file that contains records belonging to 10 different schemas. I am developing a spark app where I read the whole file, cleanse the data (I am using RDD transformations, I can't use a DF since there is no 1 schema.

Sample CSV :

```
Record1,test,name,id
Record10,test8,customer,value,info,id
Record9,record,door,lamp,sofa,tv,sink,table,box,window
```

Once the record is cleansed, for each schema, I am creating a df from the previous RDD and then saving it in HDFS.(So 10 dataframes from the previous RDD)

My question is is there anything I do do to make it shuffle less? Like partitioning by the schema type first and then saving the data?

Your feedback is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file as text lines then map each line as a tuple with its type and actual line and then filter by type and create DataFrame.
Here is a PySpark code that may help.
In addition you can see more in this [link](https://roizaig.blogspot.com/2019/10/spark-how-to-read-json-file.html)

```
rdd = spark.sparkContext.textFile('/home/roi/repos/roizaig/top/spark/stackoverflow_answers/csv_multiple_schema.csv')

import re


def record_mapper(line):
    # I'm sure you can write better code to identify the schema type but this is the basic idea.
    # Also consider parsing the line to it's CSV value instead of additional pass on the data.
    if re.search('^.*,.*,.*,.*,.*,.*,.*,.*,.*,.*$', line) :
        #Record9,record,door,lamp,sofa,tv,sink,table,box,window
        type = 3
    elif re.search('^.*,.*,.*,.*,.*,.*$', line):
        # Record10,test8,customer,value,info,id
        type = 2
    elif re.search('^.*,.*,.*,.*$', line):
        # Record1,test,name,id
        type = 1
    return (type, line)


def part(tuple):
    return hash(tuple[0])


type_rdd = rdd.map(record_mapper, preservesPartitioning=True)
# use persist here to avoid re-calculations
type_rdd.persist(pyspark.StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)

for type in range(1, 4):
    # Since the schema type is knowen you can create a DataFrame with defined schema
    df = type_rdd.filter(lambda t: t[0] == type).toDF()
df.show()

+---+--------------------+
| _1|                  _2|
+---+--------------------+
|  1|Record1,test,name,id|
+---+--------------------+

+---+--------------------+
| _1|                  _2|
+---+--------------------+
|  2|Record10,test8,cu...|
+---+--------------------+

+---+--------------------+
| _1|                  _2|
+---+--------------------+
|  3|Record9,record,do...|
+---+--------------------+
```